# log files in realvnc gone rogue (becoming ~20G)

Tags: logging, vnc

My log files for my vnc sessions are out of control. Is there a way to limit the size of the log file or to reduce the amount without completely turning off logging?

Our other user's vnc sessions do not have this issue and everything appears to be the same.

Has anyone run into this or does anyone have suggestions?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Log parameter to *:file:10 (that will just log errors) or *:file:30 (Errors plus a few other things). If you have your setting set to *:file:100 that will log everything and is usually set like that only for debugging purposes.